# move an object from left to right in 1 minute

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I want to move an Object in Flash from left to right in 1 minute
I tried to do it like this but it is less than 1 minute

```
addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, move);

function move(e:Event):void{
    this.myObject.x += 1;
}
```

How can I move `myObject` in 1 minute and also Stop it when in end of the screen in right?

Comment: **this.myObject.x += ;** its wrong! how did you say `it is less than 1 minute`
 when the code has syntax error, _expecting identifier before semicolon._

Comment: @payamsbr sry! I have correct it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try creating a [`Tween`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/fl/transitions/Tween.html#includeExamplesSummary) by minimally editing the example given in the documentation:

```
 import fl.transitions.Tween;
 import fl.transitions.easing.*;


 var myTween:Tween = new Tween(myObject, "x", None.easeNone, 0, stage.stageWidth, 60, true);
```

You want to find the starting and end points for the position that suits your needs which are not exactly clear from your question.

Answer (score 1):

```
var duration_ms:int = 60*1000;
var offset:Number = 100;

var start_time_ms:int = getTimer();
var start_pos_x:int = mc.x;
var end_pos_x:int = mc.x+offset;
addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, Loop);

function Loop(e:event):void {
   var elapsed_ms:int = getTimer() - start_time_ms;
   if (elapsed_ms<duration_ms) {
      mc.x = start_pos_x + ((end_pos_x-start_pos_x)*(elapsed_ms/duration_ms));

   }
}
```